# Read all Captured Extended Events for a Given Extended Event Session Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I want to be able to read all XE files for a dynamic XE session name. My XE session stores files to disk.

I have the query below

```
DECLARE @XeName SYSNAME = 'MyXE'
DECLARE @Path NVARCHAR(255)
SELECT  @Path = (
                    SELECT  CONVERT(XML,target_data).value('(/EventFileTarget/File/@name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Path]
                    FROM    sys.dm_xe_sessions s
                            JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t
                                ON s.address = t.event_session_address
                    WHERE   s.name = @XeName
                )

SELECT  event_data = CONVERT(XML, event_data) 
FROM    sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(@Path, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

However, the target_data column in sys.dm_xe_session_targets only shows the most recent file in the format `C:\Trace Outputs\MyXE\MyXE_0_132109395357410000.xel`

but I need it to be `C:\Trace Outputs\MyXE\MyXE*.xel`

I can do this using some string functions to find the first _ after the last \ and replace that and all the text after with `*.xel` but I wondered if there was a nicer / easier way to do this than a load of nested string manipulation functions